# How to add a fixed value as second condition for plot?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I wanted to draw circles in the MACD when Signal line and MACD cross. This does work well. Now I want to add a second condition to only draw the circle when MACD and Signal Line cross AND when value is below, for example, 2.
What do I need to add here? This must be in the code under "Mark the cross"
I edit this post and added the complete code
And second question: How can I create an alert everytime these both conditions are true?

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence", shorttitle="MACD", timeframe="", timeframe_gaps=true)

// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))

//drawing colour zones
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
h1 = hline(2)
h2 = hline(4)
fill(h1, h2, color=color.new(color.red, 64))
h3 = hline(-2)
h4 = hline(-4)
fill(h3, h4, color=color.new(color.green, 64))

//mark the cross
plot(ta.crossover(signal,macd) ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 20, color=color.red, transp=40)
plot(ta.crossunder(signal,macd) ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 20, color=color.green, transp=40)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code doesn't work. you define value as a boolean (value=ta.cross(signal, macd) and then you try to compare it to a number : value > 10. Please post a working code.

Comment: Sorry, I just wanted to show my latest outcome, even with the mistakes. Now this is the working code, I´ve edited my initial post.

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare you condition and use it like this :

```
MyCondition =  ta.crossover(signal,macd) and value < 2  
plot( MyCondition ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 20, color=color.red, transp=40) 
alert(MyCondition, alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

[edit]
The complete code, with a test on the macd value (here < 0.00007 because i am on EUR/USD 3min) :

```
//@version=5
indicator(title="Moving Average Convergence", shorttitle="MACD")

// Getting inputs
fast_length = input(title="Fast Length", defval=12)
slow_length = input(title="Slow Length", defval=26)
src = input(title="Source", defval=close)
signal_length = input.int(title="Signal Smoothing",  minval = 1, maxval = 50, defval = 9)
sma_source = input.string(title="Oscillator MA Type",  defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])
sma_signal = input.string(title="Signal Line MA Type", defval="EMA", options=["SMA", "EMA"])

// Plot colors
col_macd = input(#2962FF, "MACD Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="MACD")
col_signal = input(#FF6D00, "Signal Line  ", group="Color Settings", inline="Signal")
col_grow_above = input(#26A69A, "Above   Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_fall_above = input(#B2DFDB, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Above")
col_grow_below = input(#FFCDD2, "Below Grow", group="Histogram", inline="Below")
col_fall_below = input(#FF5252, "Fall", group="Histogram", inline="Below")

// Calculating
fast_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, fast_length) : ta.ema(src, fast_length)
slow_ma = sma_source == "SMA" ? ta.sma(src, slow_length) : ta.ema(src, slow_length)
macd = fast_ma - slow_ma
signal = sma_signal == "SMA" ? ta.sma(macd, signal_length) : ta.ema(macd, signal_length)
hist = macd - signal
hline(0, "Zero Line", color=color.new(#787B86, 50))
plot(hist, title="Histogram", style=plot.style_columns, color=(hist>=0 ? (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_above : col_fall_above) : (hist[1] < hist ? col_grow_below : col_fall_below)))

//drawing colour zones
plot(macd, title="MACD", color=col_macd)
plot(signal, title="Signal", color=col_signal)
//h1 = hline(2)
//h2 = hline(4)
//fill(h1, h2, color=color.new(color.red, 64))
//h3 = hline(-2)
//h4 = hline(-4)
//fill(h3, h4, color=color.new(color.green, 64))

//mark the cross
plot(ta.crossover(signal,macd) ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 9, color=color.new(color.red, 40))
plot(ta.crossunder(signal,macd) ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 9, color=color.new(color.green, 40))

MyCondition =  ta.crossover(signal,macd) and macd < 0.00007
plot( MyCondition ? macd : na, style = plot.style_circles, linewidth = 20, color=color.new(color.purple, 40) )
if MyCondition
    alert( "crossover signal on macd", alert.freq_once_per_bar)
```

NB: I post the entire code because your indicator declaration at the beginning had to be changed.

Will give you this :
[image]

Comment: thank you, but it still says: Undeclared identifier 'value'. Can I use Value in v5?

Comment: @ChrischnLOK you have to declare value before, I don't know your script and what you want to do with it. You said 'when value is below'... Edit your question, pase the entire code and describe precisely your error, you will get help.

Comment: Thanks, I´ve added the complete code in the post

Comment: @ChrischnLOK what does represent your value when you say : 'AND when value is below, for example, 2.' ?

Comment: Sorry, I added a picture showing the MACD and the value scale on the right side. When there is a cross from Signal line and MACD at the value of 2 or higher, it should draw the circle, otherwise not

Comment: @ChrischnLOK did you try the code in may answer ? For the value, you can choose what you want by modifying the line MyCondition =  ta.crossover(signal,macd) and macd < 0.00007 (I take this 0.00007 value but you can use 2 or 20 as you need).

Comment: Thank you very much, this does completely work now. I really appreciate all your help here